# Load spring form by an ajax request in already rendered JSP

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Let's say there is a JSP which has been rendered to the client. On this Jsp, I created a link, I want this link to make a request to the server and server sends a spring from with command object in it and this spring form gets rendered on the already loaded page on client. I mean I do not want whole page to be loaded. Let's take a scenario like there is link 'update contact details' on my page. Clicking on this link makes an ajax request to the server and spring form is sent from the server such that form is populated with the contact details of the user who clicked the link of 'update contact details'. Basically I want stuff like header and footer not to be loaded unnecessarily every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you have a link as,

```
<a id="screenId" href="#">
```

then add `<div id="container"></div>` somewhere you want your page, also a js function as,

```
$('#screenId').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         cache: false,
         url: "yourControllerURL",
         data: "",
         success: function(response){
             $('#container').html(response);
         }
    });
});
```

with the above ajax call, inside your controller, return your jsp with the command object. The controller code may look something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="yourControllerURL") 
public String includeAnotherJSP(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("commandObjectName", commandObject);
    return "yourJSPMapping/jspName";
}
```

After your controller will send the response, you will get the required JSP inside the response and you can then load that into your `<div id="container">` using above js code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vaibhav, just one thing that $('#container').load(response) did not worked, hence I used append(response) for the time being.

Comment: Your welcome Vikky, for that you can also try ('#container').html(response) if you want to change it.