# Call a jsp Page in an iframe

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, iframe, methods

I am working on an interface using JSP pages and Javascript. My Project Structure is shown here.

[image: project structure]

In my main JSP page(`veditor.jsp`) under views, I have a Properties Panel division.

[image: pic1]

**veditor.jsp**

```
...
<!--Container/Canvas-->

    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>

<!--Properties Panel-->

    <div style="float: left" class="property" id="propertypane">
        <h1 class="toolbox-titlex" id="toolbox-titlex">Properties</h1>
        <iframe class = "panel" id="lot"></iframe> 
    </div>
...
```

Here I need to call the `selectClauseForm.jsp` page within the `veditor.jsp`'s iframe in the Properties Panel using the `veditor.js` Javascript.

**veditor.js**

```
if (dropElem == "stream ui-draggable") {
    var newAgent = $('<div>').attr('id', i).addClass('streamdrop');
    var elemType = "table";

    $("#container").addClass("disabledbutton");
    $("#toolbox").addClass("disabledbutton");
    $('#container').append(newAgent);

    callSelectClauseForm();
}

function callSelectClauseForm()
{
    alert("Called before");
    document.getElementById("lot").src = 'selectClauseForm.jsp';
    alert("Called after");
}
```

I am getting both the alerts within the `callSelectForm()` method but the Properties panel is not loading and am getting the following error.

[image: error]

As shown above, when calling the `createTableForm(...)` method, I need to call the `selectClauseForm.jsp` within the iframe in the `veditor.jsp`.

Is this because my path is wrong in the `src` location?
Any suggestions on how I can load the jsp inside the iframe using Javascript will be highly appreciated as I am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136831/load-spring-form-by-an-ajax-request-in-already-rendered-jsp).
Which load jsp file and add that response content in div.You can achieve same in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a controller mapping for this jsp as follows,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "clause")
public class ClauseController {

  @RequestMapping(value="selectClause") 
  public String selectClause(ModelMap model) {
    return "selectClauseForm.jsp";
  }
}
```

Then you can call the url inside the iframe src,

```
function callSelectClauseForm() {
    alert("Called before");
    document.getElementById("lot").src = 'clause/selectClause';
    alert("Called after");
}
```